# コンソールに表示されたワーニングを削除するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

Tags: reactjs

React 17, React Hook Form v7, yup, Semantic-uiという環境にてReact学習中です。

共通コンポーネントを作成した際、以下のワーニングがコンソールに出力されました。

```
index.js:1 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `Controller`.
    at EmailField (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:947:5)
    at Controller (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:50587:35)
    at RhfEmailField (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2229:15)
    at form
    at Form (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:62341:29)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:3737:70)
    at Outlet (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:54276:10)
    at main
    at AppLayout
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:54329:5)
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:132:71)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:54301:5)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:53799:5)
```

おそらく、作成したコンポーネントでrefを指定していないためだと思っております。
refについての理解が弱いところが原因と思います。どのように対応してよいかアドバイスいただけないでしょうか？

入力チェックは行われますが、コンソールのワーニングが消せるのであれば消したいです。

よろしくお願いします。

package.json

```
{
  "name": "sfp-symphony",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.8.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.1.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.37",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "node-sass": "5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.3",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.16.1",
    "react-query": "^3.23.2",
    "react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "fix": "npm run -s format && npm run -s lint:fix",
    "format": "prettier --write --loglevel=warn '{public,src}/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,html,gql,graphql,json}'",
    "lint": "npm run -s lint:style; npm run -s lint:es",
    "lint:fix": "npm run -s lint:style:fix && npm run -s lint:es:fix",
    "lint:es": "eslint 'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'",
    "lint:es:fix": "eslint --fix 'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'",
    "lint:conflict": "eslint-config-prettier 'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'",
    "lint:style": "stylelint 'src/**/*.{css,less,sass,scss}'",
    "lint:style:fix": "stylelint --fix 'src/**/*.{css,less,sass,scss}'",
    "preinstall": "typesync || :",
    "prepare": "simple-git-hooks > /dev/null"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.173",
    "@types/node-sass": "4.11.2",
    "@types/prettier": "^2.2.3",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/stylelint": "^9.10.1",
    "@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "^5.9.5",
    "@types/testing-library__user-event": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.13",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.20.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.20.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "^1.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.2.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "simple-git-hooks": "^2.3.1",
    "stylelint": "^13.12.0",
    "stylelint-config-recess-order": "^2.3.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^21.0.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^4.1.0",
    "typesync": "^0.8.0"
  },
  "simple-git-hooks": {
    "pre-commit": ". ./lint-staged-around",
    "pre-push": ". ./test-around"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "prettier --write --loglevel=error",
      "eslint --fix --quiet"
    ],
    "src/**/*.{css,less,sass,scss}": [
      "stylelint --fix --quiet"
    ],
    "{public,src}/**/*.{html,gql,graphql,json}": [
      "prettier --write --loglevel=error"
    ]
  }
}
```

App.tsx

```
import { VFC } from 'react';
import { Button, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { YupJa as yup } from 'utils/validations/yup/i18n/YupJa';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { RhfEmailField } from 'components/organisms/elements';

type FormValues = {
  email: string;
  email2: string;
};

const schema = yup.object({
  email: yup.string().required().email().label('メールアドレス'),
  email2: yup.string().required().email().label('メールアドレス'),
});

const App: VFC = () => {
  const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm<FormValues>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  const handleLogin: SubmitHandler<FormValues> = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <Form size="large" onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleLogin)}>
      <RhfEmailField
        id="email"
        name="email"
        placeholder="メールアドレス"
        label="メールアドレス"
        required
        showIcon
        control={control}
      />

      <Button color="teal" fluid size="large">
        Click
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
};
export default App;
```

RhfEmailField.tsx

```
/* eslint-disable react/destructuring-assignment,
                  @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment,
                  @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access,
                  @typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions
*/
import { VFC } from 'react';
import EmailField from 'components/molecules/elements/EmailField';
import { Controller, DeepMap, FieldError, FieldValues } from 'react-hook-form';
import { FormInputProps } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { InputFieldProps } from 'components/molecules/elements/ElementProps';

export type RhfEmailFieldProps = InputFieldProps & FormInputProps;

export const RhfEmailField: VFC<RhfEmailFieldProps> = (props) => (
  <Controller
    name={props.name}
    control={props.control}
    defaultValue=""
    render={({ field, formState: { errors } }) => (
      <EmailField
        label={props.label}
        id={props.id}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        isRequired={props.required}
        showIcon={props.showIcon}
        {...field}
        errorMessage={
          errors[props.name] &&
          `${(errors[props.name] as DeepMap<FieldValues, FieldError>)?.message}`
        }
      />
    )}
  />
);

export default RhfEmailField;
```

EmailField.tsx

```
import { VFC } from 'react';
import ErrorMessage from 'components/atoms/elements/ErrorMessage';
import { Form, Input } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { InputFieldProps, RhfRegisterInputFieldProps } from './ElementProps';

type EmailFieldProps = InputFieldProps & RhfRegisterInputFieldProps;

const EmailField: VFC<EmailFieldProps> = (props: EmailFieldProps) => {
  const {
    label,
    id,
    placeholder,
    isRequired,
    showIcon,
    errorMessage,
    value,
    onChange,
    onBlur,
  } = props;
  const icon: string = showIcon ? 'mail' : '';
  const iconPosition: 'left' | undefined = showIcon ? 'left' : undefined;

  return (
    <Form.Field required={isRequired}>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <Input
        type="email"
        id={id}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        icon={icon}
        iconPosition={iconPosition}
        error={!!errorMessage}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        onBlur={onBlur}
      />
      <ErrorMessage message={errorMessage} />
    </Form.Field>
  );
};

export default EmailField;
```

ElementProps.tsx

```
import { ChangeEventHandler, FocusEventHandler } from 'react';
import { RefCallBack } from 'react-hook-form';

export type InputFieldProps = {
  label?: string;
  id?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  isRequired?: boolean;
  showIcon?: boolean;
  errorMessage?: string | undefined;
};

export type RhfRegisterInputFieldProps = {
  inputRef?: RefCallBack;
  value: string;
  onChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
  onBlur: FocusEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`field` が展開されて `EmailField` の `ref` プロパティが設定されてしまっているのが原因でしょう。

```js
export const RhfEmailField: VFC<RhfEmailFieldProps> = (props) => (
  <Controller
    // ...
    render={({ field, formState: { errors } }) => (
      <EmailField
        // ...
        {...field} // ref={ref} 相当
        // ...
      />
    )}
  />
```

[リファレンスのサンプルコード](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller)通りに書けば良いかと思います。

```js
export const RhfEmailField: VFC<RhfEmailFieldProps> = (props) => (
  <Controller
    // ...
    render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, ref }, formState: { errors } }) => (
      <EmailField
        // ...
        onChange={onChange}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        value={value}
        inputRef={ref} // ref でなく inputRef
        // ...
      />
    )}
  />
```

Comment: ご連絡いただいた通り変更すると解消しました！
ありがとうございます。

リファレンスを読み落とさないようにします。